# How to revert an image in pixastic when an element is clicked?

Tags: jquery, pixastic

I just tried following code to blur an image , it works well. But i want to revert back when an element is clicked, how can I do this ?

```
$(window).bind("load",function() {

         $(".testclass").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0.9});
    $(".clickclass").click(function(e){
        // this statement should revert the image
                });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but give this a try:

```
$(".clickclass").click(function(e){
      $(this).pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0}); //This should remove the blur
});
```

**EDIT**: Another stab in the dark:

```
$(".clickclass").click(function(e){
      Pixastic.revert(this);
 })
```

Comment: i tried that edited one as well , it doesn't work. it would be great to find an alternative way to blur an image instead of using pixastic plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
adding [0] made a big difference. Definitely did the trick for me. Give it a try

Pixastic.revert($(this).find('.imageUrl')[0]);

Another thing is i had to create a VAR as pixastic creates a duplicate canvas

This is my whole function

$(function () {

        $('.col1.w1').mouseenter(function () {


            var origImg = ($(this).find('.imageUrl'));
            if (origImg.is('img')) {
                Pixastic.process(origImg[0], 'blurfast', { amount: 2 });
            }


        });
        $('.col1.w1').mouseout(function () {
            var origImg = ($(this).find('.imageUrl'));
            Pixastic.revert($(this).find('.imageUrl')[0]);


        });
    });
```